# Updating component prop when standalone in vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When creating a generic component often we will want it to work as as a standalone component or as a child to a larger component.

I'm trying to find the best way to do this in Vuejs2. It seems like the approach would be to use a combination of *props* and *custom events*.

I have created an example using a `check-list` to illustrate the issue: https://codepen.io/duprasa/pen/LmLRjE

I also created this diagram to further illustrate the issue
[image]

I have read the vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) on props and they don't mention what to do in this case and warn against the strategy I'm currently using.

I think this is a fairly common pattern and it would be useful to know what the best strategy to deal with it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your component `checkList` has too many responsibilities. 
If you want your component to be reusable, it should have only one responsibility: displays the list of items, and emits an event when an item is selected. It should not update the item by itself.

The component using the `check-list` (`app`) can handle the event and update the item `selected` property. It also provides the `check-list` with the items to display.

You can introduce a new component, say `standalone-check-list`, that would provide a default set of items for the checklist and handle the event to update the list accordingly. Then use `standalone-check-list` as a standalone component.

Comment: Thanks Laure, I'm still not entirely convinced that you are right and that it has too many responsibilities, but you might be right. I honestly didn't think about making a `standalone-check-list`, that would work, just feels a bit verbose/redundant, but it might be the best way. You have given me food for thought, thanks :)